# Create a Form to upload files to Dropbox

Tags: php, forms, upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to create a form to upload files to Dropbox using the Core API:

```
require_once('dropbox-php/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php');

use \Dropbox as dbx;

if ($_POST) {

    $file_to_upload = $_POST['file_to_upload'];

    // Connect to Dropbox using the configuration in the app-info.json file

    $appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("wp-content/themes/blankwptheme/app-info.json");

    $accessToken = "jNw7IwVafasfasdfadfasdfsK_4-S4sfmO2vyafdafadsfa25BhC";

    $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
    $accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

    // Upload File to Dropbox

    $f = fopen($file_to_upload, "rb");
    $result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/Uploads/" . $file_to_upload, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
    fclose($f);
    print_r($result);

}
```

---

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file_to_upload" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The code works fine when I use a hard-coded path to a file stored on the server:

```
$f = fopen("text.txt", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/Uploads/text.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
```

But I want the user to be able to choose a file on their computer using the form and then have it upload to Dropbox.

My issue is that the file is expected to be on the server already... is there a way to bypass this step?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at there JS api. :)

Comment: If you want to upload a file from the end-user's computer/browser via your server, you will need to upload the file to your server first normally. 

Otherwise, you can upload directly from the user's browser (e.g., using [dropbox-sdk-js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js)) but if you only want to upload to your own browser, that's not recommended as you'd leak your own access token to the user.

Comment: @Greg thanks for the explanation. I have modified it to upload to the server first and it works fine now. Thanks!